# Add 1 to a database value when button is pressed using Django

Tags: python, html, django, web

I have a django model that looks like this:

```py
class Character(models.Model):
character_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(1)], default=1)

def __str__(self):

    return self.character_Name
```

with an html file(main.html) that looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
        <body>
          <h1>{{ characters.character_Name }}</h1>
          <h4>Level: {{ characters.level }}</h4>
          <button onclick="increase_level()"> + 1 </button>
        </body>
```

a function in views.py that looks like this:

```py
def main(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        characters = Character.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('character_Name').first
        return render(request, 'main.html', {'characters': characters})
    else:
        return redirect('account creation')
```

and its path from urls.py:

```py
path('main', views.main, name='main'),
```

*How can I implement the press of the button updating the page and the database by leveling up by 1?*

Answer (score 0):

Create a view, in this view do this:

```
character = Character.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('character_Name').first()
character.level = F('level') + 1
character.save()
```

before this you need to import F

```
from django.db.models import F
```

Now in your html on the button press make an ajax request to this view that you have made.
**Edit**: since you want it to update the page you are on it doesn't need to be an ajax request. just make the button an anchor tag with this views url and at the end of the view redirect to the same url you were on (the one with the button).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure... but I will try something like that :

in the urls.py

```
 path('addone/<int:pk>/<int:level>', views.change_level, name='change_level'),
```

in the html file

```
 <a href="{% url 'YOURAPP:change_level' characters.id characters.level  %}">Add 1</a>
```

in the view

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

 @login_required
 def change_level(request, level, pk):

     character_selected = Character.objects.get(pk=pk)

     new_level = level + 1
     character_selected.level = new_level
     character_selected.save()

     return redirect('YOURAPP:main')
```